# What is the preferred method to manage an nvidia (or any) GPU?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, amd

After a fresh new install of Void Linux, and installing the nvidia drivers, I'm beginning to think nvidia-settings is not the preferred way to manage GPU settings. The app is absolutely broken compared to legacy versions to the point that:

1. anything configured is not maintained
2. resolution up-scaling is [not handled correctly](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmacXrdR2RFbj2bv34qVsN1FzmvB9Lh5TsVBj9TnByCq2N) (ViewPortIn: 1600x1200; ViewPortOut: 1280x1024+0+0)
3. advanced functionality is almost non-existent (eg: fan curves and rendering on a 2nd GPU)
4. fan speed control only applies up to a limited value (eg: 74%)

After more than 4 years of reporting these issues and nothing being done but them getting worse, I believe there's another more preferred method that actually functions like it's supposed to. Does anyone know what that might be?

The answer to this should also benefit AMD users, as I've run into this same exact dilemma with an AMD card, so AMD answers are also open here.

Comment: Just want to comment I've recently gotten an AMD GPU somewhat working (can't control anything about it), and it looks like it backs this question since there's nothing similar to nvidia-settings for it.

Comment: seems to be that going through the pain of manually building an `xorg.conf` is the preferred method, since that's the only common ground for all GPUs.